# disable breadcrumbs globally in Yii

Tags: yii

Yii generates breadcrumbs on every view page via Gii.  I would like to know a way to programmatically disable all breadcrumbs on every view.

Otherwise, I think the css way would work.  But I feel like a waste to generate code on the server only to hide them on the client side.

```
.breadcrumbs{
  display:none
 }
```

I looked at detachbehavior, and failed to find useful example.  Is it even related?  Please kindly advice.  Thanks

Comment: I just realized that I can comment out the code below in the layotus/main.php to disable breadcrumbs for the entire site.

     <?php
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
  'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
 )); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->

Comment: And I just realized you found out my answer already.  Nice job sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breadcrumbs exist in the main.php viewfile.  This file is under /protected/views/layouts/main.php.

If you eliminate the line where it says:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
    'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
)); ?><!-- breadcrumbs -->
```

You shouldn't see it in any other view unless you explicitly put it there.

Answer (score 0):

you can also copy the gii templates and change the view files.

from framework/gii/generators/crud/templates/default to protected/gii/generators/crud/templates/default

and when you generate the crud only select the new templates